# How long is message locked for specified subscriber in ActiveMQ using STOMP?

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I want read messages from ActiveMQ with multiple consumers without repeated read.

How long is message locked after SUBSCRIBE if it is locked at all?

Is it until disconnect or timeout?

I am using ActiveMQ but not understand protocol.

Answer (score 1):

This messaging feature (usually present across all brokers and protocols) is often referred to as "acknowledgement" or "ack". STOMP defaults to "auto", which means when the client receives the message, and the broker automatically marks it as delivered.

There are other ack modes which allow the developer more control over when the ack is returned-- for example, if you want to wait until a database insert has successfully completed. Inversely, the client can roll a message back or NACK the message, which instructs the broker that this client rejects the receipt of the message.

There is also full transaction support in STOMP.

Details in STOMP API examples and the specification here:

stomp spec ref: https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SUBSCRIBE_ack_Header

Comment: With STOMP Auto ack, the broker actually marks the message as ack'd on dispatch, there is no return traffic from the client to ack messages in that mode.

Comment: Let's not talk about auto mode which no use any locking just send message without care if they processed or not. This subject is unrelated to question. More important is when client individual confirmation is need.

Comment: Edited to clarify auto ack behavior in STOMP is different than JMS h/t @TimBish

Comment: @Chameleon will you please accept the answer?  Thanks

Comment: Sure - need to check if useful.